# How to have user input 2nd value after a one line two value input?

Tags: python, multiplication

What I mean by this question is, if I wanted to have the user input two values to determine the product of those two values within a single line, but the user hits enter after only inputting the first value, how would I fall back to a second input so that they may enter the second value?
I have my code here:

```
num1 = 0
num2 = 0
num1, num2 = map(int, input("Input two numbers you'd like the product of separated by a space: ").split())
#num2 = int(input())
if(
    num2 == 0
    num2 = int(input())
    return num2
)
    

product = num1 * num2

print("\n")
print("The result is ", product)
```

You can see I attempted an if statement there, but I really wasn't sure where I was going with it. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Verify that they entered two things before calling `int()` on the parts.

```
numbers = input("Input two numbers ...")
split_numbers = numbers.split()
if len(split_numbers) != 2:
    print("You must enter two numbers!  please try again")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check how many values were entered before you try to assign to two variables. If the user enters only one value, the assignment will get an error, it won't assign `0` to the second variable.

```
while True:
    values = input("Input two numbers you'd like the product of separated by a space: ").split()
    if len(values) == 2:
        try:
            num1, num2 = map(int, values)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("You didn't enter numbers")
    else:
        print("You didn't enter two values, try again")
```